# How do I manage web storage "browser limits" settings in IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer, web-storage

Using Internet Explorer 11 to access my company's internal web application (which uses web storage), it appears it exceeds the default limits of the browser, then prompts me to allow to exceed.  I get the message ...

*"Do you want to allow bogushost.bogusdomain.com to use additional storage on your computer?"*

... at which point I click a button "Yes" and it will continue to run correctly.  If I choose the button "Not for this site" the application does not run because it was pre-emptively cut off.  What controls the limits, and how to I adjust for my specific site in Internet Explorer 11?  I would like to increase the limits across the domain so users do not receive such a question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, based on an [answer by Rob^_^ at social.technet.microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/419350ab-84d2-4b63-97ee-439b59749b05/do-you-want-to-allow-outlookcom-to-use-additional-storage-on-your-computer?forum=ieitprocurrentver), the (paraphrased) answer is as follows...

For security reasons MSIE browsers initially allow a maximum of 10Mb of local storage per website.... Other browsers are yet to mitigate this possible security flaw.

Tools>Internet Options>General tab, Browsing History section, 'Settings' button, Website Databases and caching.

Either increase the allowed storage limit or uncheck the option to allow websites to use local storage.